# Причастный оборот [4]

Tags: причастный-оборот

Найдите в этом предложении ошибки:

> Учтите, что в причастный оборот не входит определяемое им существительное.

Answer (score 2):

Какие ошибки? Орфографических нет, пунктуационных нет. Ошибка в оглавлении - причасТный. По сути тоже допускается выражение. Есть определяемое слово(сущ.), к нему относится определение, выраженное причастным оборотом, т.е. оборот определяет его.Существительное, определяемое причастным оборотом, - всё нормально. Если быть формалистом, то "в причастный оборот не входит существительное, к которому он(оборот)относится"